# Windows Azure Tools Encryption Certificate for Extensions has not been installed properly

Tags: c#, azure, encryption, certificate, azure-cloud-services

I've just deployed my cloud service with the usual configuration, but now a worker role has been getting busy and recycling over and over again.

I am getting the below message from the diagnostics:

There is no appropriate cert in the store LOCAL_MACHINE\MY to decrypt the data, the data must be decrypted with the cert with serial number 117aa8b629a73b9e466f5e7cabec86dc and issued by 'DC=Windows Azure Tools Encryption Certificate for Extensions'. Please make sure this cert is installed to the store LOCAL_MACHINE\MY along with the corresponding private key.

But it does not seem to be the root cause, as it is a cert generated by Azure.

Has anyone gone through something similar? How have you found the real issue?

Comment: Anyone have anything on this?

Comment: In my case, it turns out to be an unhandled exception which I eventually caught running locally. 

Microsoft describes in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-troubleshoot-common-issues-which-cause-roles-recycle) a number of possible causes for this behaviour, it might be usefull.